# Adding different left icon to expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am having expandable listview and how to add the icon to listview. any body help me to this.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Yes, add it in your adapter in the `getChildView` method. You can inflate a custom layout, which has a left icon...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to show us a simple code that you have written for your app about expandable list view. But still i am assuming you have created separate XMLS for child and parent layout.

Create a separate xlm for your parent layout exmaple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@color/activity_main_bg">


<Imageview
        android:id="@+id/img_thumb
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="odp"
        android:


<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/ch1_group"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/backg"
    />
```

Suppose you want to put image in your child element you can create same xmls described as above.

and then set values using adapters.
DO NOT COPY CODE as it may not work for your case try to create as your requirement.

this link would probably help you for detail understaning.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/